# In Perforce merge, what do Base and Theirs mean?

Tags: perforce

I'm using p4merge (p4v -merge) with Perforce and am uncertain what the terms "Base" and "Theirs" refer to.

Is Base the same as the current head? (Doesn't seem to be)

Does Theirs contain the changes someone else submitted to head? (Since what point?)

Answer (score 0):

I'm told that Base is the common ancestor of your version and the version you are merging.
And Theirs is the version you are merging.

Answer (score 0):

- "Yours" is always the file in your workspace.
- "Theirs" is always the file in the depot.
- "Base" is the base of the three-way merge (usually but not always the closest common ancestor) -- a three-way merge diffs the two "legs" (theirs and yours) vs the "base" and combines the diffs into a merge result.  If the "base" is a common ancestor this results in combining all changes from "theirs" and "yours", but non-ancestor bases can also be used to facilitate "cherry-pick" operations.

In the scenario where you're resolving different revisions of the same file, "yours" is your local edit and "theirs" is some newer revision that was (presumably) submitted by someone else while you were working on your edit.

In an integrate/merge scenario the nomenclature is less intuitive, because maybe you own both branches and consider them both to be "yours", but for the purposes of resolve "yours" is always the file that you are currently working on in your workspace, and "theirs" is always the file that's being merged into "yours".